# Placing pins optimally on axis as an arithmetic progression

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

I have pins placed randomly on the x-axis, and know the location of all these pins. Say there are `n` of them. I have to move all of these pins on the x-axis between two limits `[A,B]` such that the new positions form an arithmetic progression of difference `k`. I should do this such a way that `SUM(|oldpos(i) - newpos(i)|) for each pin i` is minimum. To make it easy, for now I'm considering all pins to move from/to integer locations only.

I don't know if this can be done in some optimal time complexity. One thing I'm sure of is that after the optimal arrangement, the pins in new position will be sorted just like in their older position.

One `O(k.n)` method is to choose the progression that starts at A (i.e, place the first pin at A, and every subsequent pin at A+k, A+2k and so on). Calculate the `SUM` for this. Now do the same with every pin at A+1, A+1+k, A+2+2k and so on. The minimum will be the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, you can construct a solution that preserves order. But this is not necessarily the only solution. Consider the following example with targets `T1` and `T2` and source points `S1` and `S2` (that you want to move to the targets):

```
      T1    T2
S1    S2
```

As you see, there are two solutions:

1. move `S1` to `T1` and `S2` to `T2`
2. move `S1` to `T2` and keep `S2` at `T1`

The total cost of both solutions is exactly the same because you use the absolute value as your cost norm. This would look differently if you used the squared norm or other norms.

Now since you know the correspondence between your input points and the target points (just assume a progression starting at `A` for now), you only need to optimize for the offset:

```
minimize_offset SUM_i (|T_i + offset - oldpos(i)|)
```

Without formal proof, the solution is `offset = median(oldpos(i) - T_i)`. The intuition is that the median of both sequences must be located at the same position. You can verify that by visualizing what happens when you change the offset. For some source points, the cost will increase, for some it will decrease, depending on the direction of those points to their corresponding target points and the direction in which you changed the offset. The key point is that the absolute value of these changes will all be the same if neither of the points change the side with respect to their corresponding target points (because you used absolute value norm). So if there are as many points with their correspondences to their left as there are points with correspondences to their right, you cannot further decrease the cost because as soon as you decrease the cost for one of those sets, you will increase the cost for the other set by the same amount.

Anyway, the median can be calculated in *O(n log n)* with a naive approach or *O(n)* with median of medians. If you get a solution with target points that are outside of your valid interval, you have to truncate the offset accordingly. And as a matter of fact, the initial assumption of the target points (starting at `A`) does not need to be made. You can assume any start, e.g. `0`.

Btw, this sounds very similar to [a former project of mine](https://nicoschertler.wordpress.com/2014/06/13/matching-error-prone-sequences-of-numbers-e-g-time-codes-to-each-other/). You may want to take a look.

### Example

Here is an example for your given input

```
S     = (4, 7, 9, 13, 16)
k=3.
```

Step 1: Construct an arbitrary target sequence with `k=3`:

```
T     = (0, 3, 6, 9, 12)
```

Step 2: Calculate the sequence `S - T`

```
S - T = (4, 4, 3, 4, 4)
```

Step 3: Calculate the median of `S - T`:

```
median(S - T) = 4
```

Add this offset to `T` and you have your final sequence:

```
F = (4, 7, 10, 13, 16)
S = (4, 7,  9, 13, 16)
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit with some example? Like say the original sequence is 4, 6, 10, 13, and I need to convert this into an arithmetic sequence that lies inside [0, 40].

Comment: Sure, what is the `k` you want to use?

Comment: Actually let the sequence be 4,7,9,13,16 with difference 3

Comment: Added the example.

Comment: What is the final F I get starts before the bound? Then is the optimal F the one that starts right at the bound? Similarly for those that end after the bound.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what I meant with truncating the offset.

Comment: Also how should I select median if S has even elements?

Comment: The median is well-defined for even-numbered sequences (take the mean of the two center elements). However, in this special case, you can select any number between the two center elements. The cost will not change.

Comment: Thank you! I just need to think more on why `offset = median(oldpos(i) - T_i)`.